# What is the difference between AIM, AIP and AIS in the US?

Tags: aim

I know that in the US there exist documents which are published by the FAA such as the Aeronautical Information Manual (AIM) and the Aeronautical Information Publication (AIP). What is the difference of each one? What is their relationship with the Aeronautical Information Service (AIS)?

Comment: An [AIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_Information_Publication), e.g. Brazil AIP, is the local implementation of ICAO annex 15 rules and encompasses aeronautical information like airport information, approach plates and routes, [AIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_Information_Service) is the information service provided by ICAO members, like NOTAMS and circulars. AIS includes AIP publication. AIS is currently transiting to AIM to use more modern means of communication.

Answer (score 3):

From the beginning section of the Aeronautical Information Manual (AIM).

> This manual is designed to provide the aviation community with basic flight information and ATC procedures for use in the National Airspace System (NAS) of the United States. An international version called the Aeronautical Information Publication contains parallel information, as well as specific information on the international airports for use by the international community.
>
> This manual contains the fundamentals required in order to fly in the United States NAS. It also contains items of interest to pilots concerning health and medical facts, factors affecting flight safety, a pilot/controller glossary of terms used in the ATC System, and information on safety, accident, and hazard reporting.

**Aeronautical Information Publication** front section

> 2.1 The AIP is prepared in accordance with the Standards and Recommended Practices (SARP) of Annex 15 to the Convention on International Civil Aviation and the Aeronautical Information Services Manual (ICAO Doc 8126). Charts contained in the AIP are produced in accordance with Annex 4 to the Convention on International Civil Aviation and the Aeronautical Chart Manual (ICAO Doc 8697). Differences from ICAO Standards, Recommended Practices and Procedures are given in subsection GEN 1.7.

**[Aeronautical Information Services](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/)**

- Is the authoritative government source for collecting, validating,
  storing, maintaining, and disseminating aeronautical data for the U.
  S. and its territories.
- Develops and maintains all public instrument flight procedures and airways.
- Serves as the FAA's aeronautical charting authority for the development, publication, and dissemination of aeronautical charts and products to support aviation and to meet demand for increased capacity, efficiency, and predictability in the airspace, routes, and airports of the NAS.